# Is 一緒に needed in this case?

Tags: grammar, syntax

Is `一緒に` needed in this case？

> **A:** 買い物へ行きたい。
>
> **B:** そう。
>
> **A:** 一緒に行きましょうか？

Or is it just ->> `行こう`？

Comment: B's response to A does not make much sense. You need 一緒に if you want to say "together".

Comment: I was wondering if it was redundant or not to use 一緒に行きましょうか
is it already implied that i am referring to B there for don't need to use 一緒に？

Comment: You need it in this case anyway. If you don't use it, B will be confused.

Comment: I think the question is fine. Let's try and be a little more relaxed about simple questions. He's clearly asking if the 行こう form of 行く already implies that people will do it together, or if 一緒に is necessary. It's not ambiguous, and if you feel there are other issues, like the difference between grammatical acceptance and practical usage, then let's explore those in an answer. Nothing wrong with answering with lots of variant information. The only part of the question that's wrong is having "Question!" at the top. Now *that's* redundant ;)

Comment: A's style is inconsistent. In A's first sentence, the plain form is used, and in the second, the polite form is used. This makes it strange besides your main point. It does not sound like a conversation because of this.

Answer (score 2):

I think「一緒に」is necessary, but it will be better to say 「一緒に行きませんか」( if Aーさん isn't close to Bーさん) or「一緒に行かない？」( if B-さん is a friend). It's more polite.